# Formulating and solving a Linear/Quadratic Mixed Constraint Problem for a Single Variable using ADMM

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I've recently come across an optimization problem of the form (in matlab, [] indicating a matrix):

**Minimize: f(x)**

f(x)=sum(x) or sum(x.^2)

**Under the constraints:**

1. [C+]*x>=d+
2. [C-]*x<=d-
3. A*x=b

---

While there are different ways to solve this type of problem, I would like to use ADMM.  I am new to optimization and have been following this guide to a similar problem:
https://towardsdatascience.com/an-admm-newton-method-for-inequality-constrained-optimization-37a470c58a5c

In block matrix form (and matlab notation), I have formulated the problem as:

let: **A'=[C+;C-;A]**
In my case: **A'=[I;-I;A]**

let: **s'=[s+;s-;0]**
Where s+ and s- are slack variables for the inequality constraints

let: **c=[d+;d-;b]**

Together, the constraints are:

**[A']*x-s'-c=0**

---

In keeping with the hyperlink above, I am performing ADMM using the scaled formulation of ADMM using the vector **u** as a scaled lagrange multiplier.

Taken from the source linked above, here are the update equations I am following:

[Equations (Don't have enough reputation to link picture directly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YltW.png)

With the exception that I am utilizing:
**[A']*x-s'** in place of **[A]*x** in the image above

---

I have adapted the problem into an algorithm in Matlab, but the algorithm only appears to find a solution that is bound by the inequality constraints, but fails to be bound to **[A]*x=b**

As far as I can tell, having 0 at the tail of **s'** should guarantee that **[A]*x=b**, yet the algorithm seems to ignore the constraint entirely.  Is there an additional update step for equality conditions in ADMM?

I, like the link, am using a Newton solver to identify minimums, both by line-search and by single-step Newton-step, and confirm it is working properly.

---

In conclusion, I would like to know:

1. If this formulation is a valid one for ADMM?
2. If there are additional steps required to simultaneously solve a problem that has both equality and inequality constraints?

---

I apologize for the somewhat strange formatting of this question.  I'm not sure how to stop the editor from removing the formatting whitespace.

I can provide the matlab code if this would help as well.

Comment: Please describe your problem using MathJax (for instance, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems to me that your inequality constraints are also equality constraints. I would not do that. I would keep the inequality and equality constraints separate.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, it can be written as 
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{minimize}_{x}  & &\left\| x\right\|_p^p \\
&\mathrm{subject \ to} & 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix} 
-C_{+} \\
C_{-}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{= P}
x &\leq 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix} 
-d_{+} \\
d_{-}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{=c} \\
&& Ax&=b
\end{align}
where $p \in {1,2}$, and the inequality is componentwise.

Comment: If yes, then your problem is convex. If I were you, I would first try using CVX solver.